# I'm unable to fix the JOption error in Java, GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, syntax, software-design

1- I don't get why "frmLOGIN" is giving me an error. What should I input instead?

2- what's the right syntax for JOption here? why is that an error?

I tried changing JOption to JOptionpane but I don't think that fixes the issue
I also tried changing frmLOGIN to lblLogIn but that changes the JFrame which shouldn't occur.

```
JButton btnExit = new JButton("EXIT");
btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frmLOGIN = new JFrame("EXIT");
    if (JOption.showConfirmDialog(frmLOGIN, "Confirm if you want to exit", "LOGIN"),
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)==JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION){
            System.exit(0); 
        }
    }
```

[this is an image go my GUI so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cU8n.png)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this :

```
btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frmLOGIN, "Confirm if you want to exit", "LOGIN",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frmLOGIN, "Confirm if you want to exit", "LOGIN",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
```

I.e. replace by YES_OPTION